# Git - Como alterar a mensagem de um commit

Tags: git

Fiz o seguinte:

```
Git add . //Adicionei todos os arquivos alterados
Git commit -m 'mensagem que quero editar'
```

Agora, antes de fazer o push, quero editar a mensagem deste commit. Como faço?

**UPDATE**

Utilizei o comando git commit --amend, o editor de texto foi aberto, apliquei as alterações.
Para finalizar o editor e aplicar as alterações, é necessário usar o comando :x

Comment: `:x` é um comando do Vim, que é um editor que já vem instalado no linux/unix e também no git-bash do Windows (e muitos outros shells também já vem com alguma versão embutida). Enfim, é um editor que não tem nada a ver com o git, a não ser o fato de que em muitos sistemas ele já vem configurado para ser o editor default - embora isso possa ser mudado nas configurações

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Só um detalhe, eu não recomendo usar `--amend` depois que vc já deu push, pois quando vc faz o push vc precisa dar um -f (force), o problema disso é que vc perde um dos stages que podem estar sendo trabalhado por outro dev, o ideal é que crie-se um novo commit e acrescente algum identificador que foi uma réplica de alteração, é bem melhor e mais seguro...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso você não tenha dado push :

```
git commit --amend
```

Mas se esse não é o caso:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~Número_de_comites_que_quer_alterar
```

Apos fazer isso um arquivo com os comites se abrirá. Você verá um cabeçalhho parecido com esse:

> ```
> pick 625d23e Mensagem 0 //Commit 1    
> pick f03fd4b Mesagem 1  //Commit 2
> ```

Altere a palavra `pick` por `reword`. Salve e feche.
Cada um dos comites será aberto e você poderá editá-los.

Comment: Caso tenha dado push me avisa que atualizarei a resposta

Comment: Seria interessante já deixar com a informação sobre push para futuras pesquisas

Comment: Funcionou, abriu o editor e fiz a alteração, mas como finalizar o editor e aplicar a alteração?

Comment: Consegui salvar as alterações usando o comando :x

Obrigado!

Comment: Que bom. Se achar a minha ou outra resposta satisfatória não deixe de marcar a pergunta como resolvida